# c# Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created System.Threading.Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

not very expert of Threading under Windows.
I have a Main WinForm that opens a child form in it's ctor.

```
public partial class Main : Form
{
    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ImgRxUI formStart = new ImgRxUI();
        formStart.MdiParent = this;
        formStart.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        formStart.Show();
    }
```

etc..

The ImgRxUI Form (child form) starts a Thread passing to 2 Actions (delegates in simple form).

```
 public partial class ImgRxUI : Form
{

    private ImgReceiver oImgReceiver = null;

    public ImgRxUI()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        this.ShowIcon = false;

        oImgReceiver = new ImgReceiver(UpdateImage, Log);
        oImgReceiver.startService();

    }



    public void UpdateImage(byte[] ProtocolType)
    {
       ...do stuff...

    }

    public void Log(string Text)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            LogMethod(Text);
            tLog.ScrollToCaret();
        });

    }

    private void LogMethod(string Text)
    {
        tLog.AppendText(Text + Environment.NewLine);
    }
```

The ImgReceiver as I said starts a thread that listens on a socket...

```
 public class ImgReceiver
{

    private Action<byte[]> ImgReceived;
    private Action<string> Log;
    private System.Threading.Thread Thread_ImgReceiver = null;

    public ImgReceiver(Action<byte[]> ImageReceivedDelegate, Action<string> LogDelegate)
    {
        
        this.ImgReceived = ImageReceivedDelegate;
        this.Log = LogDelegate;
    }

    public void startService()
    {
        Thread_ImgReceiver = new System.Threading.Thread(startListening);
        Thread_ImgReceiver.IsBackground = true;
        Thread_ImgReceiver.Start();
    }

    [SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, ControlThread = true)]
    public void killService()
    {
        Thread_ImgReceiver.Abort();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    public void startListening()
    { ...do stuff...}
```

When I close the ImgRxUI form the following event on the form itself gets called

```
 private void ImgRxUI_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        oImgReceiver.killService();            
    }
```

Hear rises the error in the title.

Wht ?

Thaks

Comment: Move the Thread starting procedure to the Load or Shown events of the Form. In the Form's Constructor, the Handle has not been created yet. Is your `Log()` method delegate called that soon?

Comment: As an aside, aborting the thread is a really bad way of stopping the service. Instead set some flag that thread can check, and close the socket so that the thread exits naturally.

Comment: Use `if(this.InvokeRequired)` to check if it needs an `Invoke` otherwise call directly

Comment: Calling `Thread.Abort()` is dangerous because it can corrupt the .NET run-time and can CORRUPT ALL REMAINING THREADS. You should only ever call `Thread.Abort()` when you are trying to forcibly close out of your program.

Comment: You also cannot create, access, or update any UI element from any other thread than the UI thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change the kill Service method to**

```
[SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, ControlThread = true)]
public void killService(Action action)
{
   action.Invoke();
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

**Change the access level Thread_ImgReceiver to public**

```
public System.Threading.Thread Thread_ImgReceiver = null;
```

**and call killService to**

```
private void ImgRxUI_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{  
    oImgReceiver.killService(new Action(delegate { oImgReceiver.Thread_ImgReceiver.Abort(); }));
}
```

Comment: Excellent thanks !
I had to add little modifications inside my code because I'm handling Sockets and those need to be closed as well, but it works.
THANKS !

Comment: One more thing (if you can). I'm quite new to Threads in Windows. I worked a lot with low level OS (FreeRTOS, etc..) and I have quite a clear idea of the concepts in this kind of OSs. Where coul I get some good documentations to catch up with Thread in Windows OS ? Thanks.

Comment: Calling `Thread.Abort()` is dangerous because it can corrupt the .NET run-time and can CORRUPT ALL REMAINING THREADS. You should only ever call `Thread.Abort()` when you are trying to forcibly close out of your program. This answer is a bad idea.

Comment: @l.raimondi I do not know much about Windows threads. But it depends on what the Windows libraries are written in, which I think is in C ++, and check the threads in C ++. But in general, the concepts of thread are common in all operating systems

Comment: @Enigmativity Suppose you want to show a pop-up to the user in 5 seconds, but due to another process, this action is canceled and another action is replaced. Some criticisms are irrational and unfair.

Comment: @Enigmativity The use of this command depends on the program and the programmer. There is no problem if the program does not have a critical process in place, but if there was a critical process, Not only this order but every other order was dangerous.

Comment: @Enigmativity That was the nature of this question. This question wanted to end the program separately from the execution of any process in this area, and this was a good way to achieve this goal.